# What word describes the action of changing the grammatical person of a sentence?

Tags: grammar

For example, if I were to change the following the example sentence from:

> I'm sure you could use your experience to help me out.

to:

> You're sure I could use my experience to help you out.

what would I be doing to that sentence?

I'm looking either for a verb to describe this action, or for a word that describes the category containing:

- pronouns like 'I', 'you', etc.,
- and inflected pronouns like 'my', 'your', etc.,
- but also verb conjugations like 'am', 'are', etc.

Comment: Does the second second sentence need "my experience", or "help me out", or neither of those and it's fine as it is? The two examples are not quite exact parallels at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

The choice of grammatical person who is doing the narration is often referred to as *[point of view](http://www.grammarly.com/handbook/sentences/shifts-writing/1/consistent-point-of-view/).* While I am not aware of a single word to describe the restructuring of a sentence in which the grammatical person is changed, the phrase **shifting point of view** might work.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was hoping for something a bit neater like "to `x` a sentence" where `x` is a single word, rather than "shift the point of view of". I'll keep looking into it, but your answer may be the only choice I have in the end!